# What does "O.D." mean in this context in "Revolutionary Road" by Richard Yates?

Tags: meaning, american-english

In "Revolutionary Road" by Richard Yates, Chapter 3, Frank is laying out the stones for a walk way, and the sentence reads as follows:

> "...he could take pleasure in the sight of his own flexed thigh, lean
>   and straining under the old O.D., ..."

Frank is wearing an old pair of army pants, so I take it that "O.D." is related to some brand or insignia.

Can someone provide the meaning of "O.D." in this context?

Comment: Number 6 in [AcronymFinder](https://www.acronymfinder.com/O.D..html) (which thankfully includes initialisms as well).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O.D. stands for "Olive Drab":

> **olive drab**
> 1: a grayish olive
> 2a: a wool or cotton fabric of an olive drab color
> b: a uniform of this fabric
> <sub>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/olive%20drab)</sub>

This was typically used in fatigues (work or battle uniforms) for U.S. troops in the 20th century.

[image: US soldiers on patrol in Vietnam: http://www.vietnammemorial.com/vietnam-war.html]

Comment: Just curious Robusto, how did you come across this? I never thought that it might refer to a color.

Comment: I once had to wear those.